# Value-added tax calculator app

Tags: javascript, css, calculator, react.js, foundation

The app calculates the tax which is included in a (given) amount. Because I'm new with both libraries (React.js and Foundation) I would appreciate hints and improvement suggestions.

[Live demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/WxxrMZ)

```js
var SelectInput = React.createClass({
  changeHandler: function(e) {
    this.props.setTaxRate(e.target.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    var options = [];
    
    for (let i = this.props.min; i <= this.props.max; i++) {
      options.push(<option value={ i } >{ i }</option>);
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <select id="tax-rate" ref="taxRate"
                onChange={ this.changeHandler }
                value={ this.props.preSelected }
                title={ this.props.title }>
          { options }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var TaxCalculator = React.createClass({
  DEFAULT_TAX_RATE: 20,
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      totalAmount: 0,
      nettoAmount: 0,
      includedTax: 0,
      taxRate: this.DEFAULT_TAX_RATE
    }
  },
  setTaxRate: function(val) {
    this.setState( {
      taxRate: parseFloat(val)
    } );
  },
  setTotalAmount: function() {
    var toCheck = parseFloat(this.refs.totalAmount.value);

    if (typeof toCheck === 'number' && toCheck === toCheck) {
      this.refs.totalAmount.classList.remove('invalid-value');
      this.refs.calculate.removeAttribute('disabled');
    
      this.setState( {
        totalAmount: toCheck.toFixed(2)
      } );
    } else {
       this.refs.totalAmount.classList.add('invalid-value');
       this.refs.calculate.setAttribute('disabled');
       this.forceUpdate();
    }
  },
  calculate: function() {     
    this.state.includedTax =
      (( this.state.totalAmount / (100 + this.state.taxRate) ) 
        * this.state.taxRate).toFixed(2);
    this.state.nettoAmount = (this.state.totalAmount - this.state.includedTax).toFixed(2);
    
    this.forceUpdate();
    this.refs.totalAmount.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  },
  reset: function() {
    this.setState( {
      totalAmount: 0,
      nettoAmount: 0,
      includedTax: 0,
      taxRate: this.DEFAULT_TAX_RATE
    } );
    this.refs.totalAmount.value = 0;
    this.refs.totalAmount.removeAttribute('disabled');
    this.refs.totalAmount.classList.remove('invalid-value');
  },
  render: function() {   
    return (
      <div className="calculator-form">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="callout secondary">
            <h3>Value-added tax calculator</h3>
            <p>Enter the total amount and the tax rate for to get the amount of the contained tax.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
            <label for="total-amount">Total amount: </label>
            <input type="text" id="total-amount" required pattern="[0-9]+"
                   ref="totalAmount" onChange={ this.setTotalAmount } 
                   title="Enter here the total amount."
                   placeholder="Please enter the total amount as a number here ..." />
          </div>
          <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
            <label for="Tax-rate">Tax rate: </label>
            <SelectInput min="1" max="99" 
              preSelected={ this.state.taxRate }
              setTaxRate={ this.setTaxRate }
              title="Enter here the tax-rate." />
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="row buttons">
          <div className="button-group expanded">
            <a className="button" onClick={ this.calculate }
               disabled="disabled" ref="calculate"
               title="Calculate the netto amount and included tax based upon the entered
                      total amount.">Calculate</a>
            <a className="warning button" onClick={ this.reset }>Reset</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div className="row">    
          <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
            <label for="included-tax">Included tax: </label>
            <input type="text" id="included-tax" className="read-only"
                   ref="includedTax"
                   value={ this.state.includedTax } />
          </div>
          <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
            <label for="netto-amount">Netto amount: </label>
            <input type="text" id="netto-amount" className="read-only"
                   ref="nettoAmount" value={ this.state.nettoAmount } />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <TaxCalculator />,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

```css
$radius: 8px;

#app {
  background-color: lighten(grey, 35%);
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

body {
  background-color: lighten(grey, 25%);
}

.invalid-value {
  border: 1px solid crimson;
  background-color: lighten(pink, 7%);
}

.container {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

label, .button {
  font-weight: 800;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-group {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.read-only {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.callout {
  margin: 0 15px 30px 15px;
}

.labeled-input input, .callout, .button, .labeled-input select {
  border-radius: $radius;
}

a.button:first-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}

a.button:nth-of-type(2) {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.callout p {
  font-family: georgia;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="app"></app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I would do, to refactor this component, is creating a bunch of `presentational components` like:

```
const Row = ({taxRate, setTotalAmount, setTaxRate}) => (
  <div className="row">
    <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
      <label for="total-amount">Total amount: </label>
      <input 
        type="text"
        required pattern="[0-9]+"
        ref="totalAmount" onChange={ setTotalAmount } 
        title="Enter here the total amount."
        placeholder="Please enter the total amount as a number here ..." />
    </div>
    <div className="labeled-input medium-12 large-6 columns">
       <label for="Tax-rate">Tax rate: </label>
       <SelectInput
         min="1" max="99" 
         preSelected={ taxRate }
         setTaxRate={ setTaxRate }
         title="Enter here the tax-rate." />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

So, splitting it up will make them more reusable, and make your code look simpler.

This syntax is supported since React 0.14..

The next thing is, don't modify your refs like this:

```
this.refs.totalAmount.value = 0;
this.refs.totalAmount.removeAttribute('disabled');
this.refs.totalAmount.classList.remove('invalid-value');
```

this is an **Anti-pattern** in React, your are degrading React to jQuery. Remember the *shit* flows always in one direction, so use `setState` or better Redux to control your data flow, and `props` in your representational components..

So, no refs modification!!!, react on every data change, by using `setState` or `redux`-actions. Split your application in presentational components and container components.